# Tar got into a for loop

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I have bunch of csv files with date in it 
I want to tar each and every day files into the separate tar.gz file . However when I do that . It got stuck for single day output or tar is created with single file for single day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making this a bit harder than it needs to be. If all you want to do is `tar` files older than `"5 days ago"`, you already know how to get the seconds since epoch for `"5 days ago"`, each day is `86400` seconds, so loop subtracting `i * 86400` seconds each time for a far as you want to go back to generate the date of interest and the tar filenames, e.g.

```
$ d=$(date -d"5 days ago" +%s)
for i in {1..30}; do 
    dt="$(date -d@$((d - i * 86400)) +%Y%m%d)"
    fn="$dt.tar.gz"
    echo "tar -czf $fn *$dt*"
done
```

It uses simply globbing to find all files matching the date to include in each daily tar file, e.g., the output from the snippet above is:

```
tar -czf 20180326.tar.gz *20180326*
tar -czf 20180325.tar.gz *20180325*
tar -czf 20180324.tar.gz *20180324*
tar -czf 20180323.tar.gz *20180323*
tar -czf 20180322.tar.gz *20180322*
tar -czf 20180321.tar.gz *20180321*
tar -czf 20180320.tar.gz *20180320*
...
tar -czf 20180304.tar.gz *20180304*
tar -czf 20180303.tar.gz *20180303*
tar -czf 20180302.tar.gz *20180302*
tar -czf 20180301.tar.gz *20180301*
tar -czf 20180228.tar.gz *20180228*
tar -czf 20180227.tar.gz *20180227*
tar -czf 20180226.tar.gz *20180226*
tar -czf 20180225.tar.gz *20180225*
```

You can easily adapt this logic to your function above and is much more efficient than a triple-pipe inside a command substitution just to generate the `DIFF` for each day.

---

**Edit in Response to Comment Re:Recursive**

Above was intended to provide an example of a simple way to compute the wanted dates and form the `tar` filename and a simple search glob to enable you to put the pieces together however you like. If you are having difficulty putting it into a form that will recursively find the file with a common date, then using `find` in a command substitution provides an easy way of making the search recursive using the same glob shown above.

The `find` command can take the form of:

```
tar -czf "$fn" $(find "$srchpath" -type f -name *"$dt"*) 2>/dev/null
```

Where `find` will search for files in `"$srchpath"` and below for files matching the *"$dt"* glob. If there are any missing days in the range, the `"tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive"` error message is redirected into the bit-bucket.

A short example script taking the `srchpath` as the first argument (default `'.'`) and the range of days before `"5 days ago"` to search (default `30`) as the second argument, you could do something like the following.

```
#!/bin/bash

srchpath="${1:-.}"      ## search path (default .)
daterng="${2:-30}"      ## date range (default 30)

test -d "$srchpath" || {    ## validate search path
    printf "error: path not found '%s'.\n" "$srchpath"
    exit 1
}
test "$daterng" -eq "$daterng" 2>/dev/null || { ## validate range
    printf "error: non-integer range entered '%s'.\n" "$daternd"
    exit 1
}
d=$(date -d"5 days ago" +%s)    ## get 5 days ago

for ((i = 1; i <= daterng; i++)); do    ## loop over days in range
    dt="$(date -d@$((d - i * 86400)) +%Y%m%d)"  ## get date yyyymmdd
    fn="$dt.tar.gz"     ## form filename yyyymmdd.tar.gz
    echo "tar -czf $fn \$(find $srchpath -type f -name *$dt*)" ## echo command
    ## recursively compress matching files (no spaces allowed in name)
    tar -czf "$fn" $(find "$srchpath" -type f -name *"$dt"*) 2>/dev/null
done
```

(**note:** the files to compress must not have spaces in their name. If that is a possibility, use the `-print0` option for `find` and pipe the output to `xargs` calling `tar`)

Comment: Thanks !! . This logic is working . But I'm using functions and arguments.however Could you please let me know . How can I define directory in the script above . Sorry for the basic questions . I got stuck .

Comment: Your answer works on the present directory . I want to define like anydir in my script.Could you please help me out

Comment: @Xizu sure. When you have the date, say `20180225`, you can simply use `tar -czf "$dt.tar.gz" $(find . -type f -name "*$dt*")` using `find` in a *command substitution* using the glob `"*$dt*"` to name match -- which will give you the recursive behavior you desire.